# Массив символов Си

Tags: массивы, c, строки, символы

Здравствуйте.
Вот код программы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    char x[]="test";
    char y[4];
    y[4]='\0';
    printf("%s", strncpy(y, x, 5)); //третий аргумент должен превышать число копируемых символов на единицу
    getch();
}
```

Если ее запустить, то будет пустая строка. Почему ничего не скопировалось в массив игрек, ведь в нем достаточно места, чтобы принять строку "test" и '\0'? А если сделать так

```
char y[2]; //изменили
y[4]='\0';
printf("%s", strncpy(y, x, 5));
```

то выводится "te". В чем причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В массиве y **недостаточно** места для для строки "test" и '\0'. Чтобы было достаточно, нужно объявлять char y[5]; (длина строки + 1)
2. Обнулять последний символ перед копированием не нужно, т.к. вы копируете 5 символов, в том числе и конечный '\0'

Comment: Я думал, что y[0]='t' , y[1]='e'... y[4]='\0'

Comment: А почему при
char y[5];
printf("%s", strncpy(y, x, 2)); выводится "te=" ? Непонятный знак равно.

Comment: > Я думал, что y[0]='t' , y[1]='e'... y[4]='\0'

Вы правильно думаете, но при объявлении нужно указывать требуемый размер (в нашем случае 5 символов), а не номер последнего символа.

> А почему при char y[5]; printf("%s", strncpy(y, x, 2)); выводится "te=" ? Непонятный знак равно.

Потому что заранее неизвестно, что лежит в y. Вы копируете только два символа из исходной строки и не вставляете после них '\0', поэтому printf выводит 2 скопированных символа, и, не встретив '\0', продолжает выводить "мусорные" символы, находящиеся после этих двух символов.

Comment: Тогда нужно вручную добавить '\0' ?

Comment: Да, нужно. Не нужно только тогда, когда строка с завершающим '\0' копируется при помощи strcpy, либо когда при помощи strncpy копируется длина строки + 1 символов, как было в первоначальном примере.

Comment: Спасибо. Я понял.

Answer (score 4):

[[@Tkas](/users/5381/tkas)](/users/5381/tkas), как правильно писать [[@insolor](/users/1365/insolor)](/users/1365/insolor) Вам ответил.

Ответ непосредственно на Ваш вопрос, ***почему*** при *char y[4]; y[4] = 0;* ***ничего не выводится***

заключается в том, что когда Вы пишете 0 в y[4], то он **заносится в x[0] (!!!)**. Память под массивы в стеке так компилятор выделил.

Соответственно printf получает пустую строку (x начинается с нуля, он копируется в y[0], Вы его "печатаете").

Вот, что произошло.

Comment: @avp, а почему он заносит в x[0]? Я же явно указал, что массив игрек. Не знал о таком)

Comment: @Tkas, по простому о таком явлении говорят - "трешь память".

Дело в том, что память под локальные переменные размещается подряд (не будем сейчас рассматривать выравнивание числовых типов). Реально Вы запросили у компилятора явно 4 байта под массив y (индексы 0,1,2,3) и неявно 5 байт под массив х.

Посмотреть адреса можно

        printf ("x[0] = %p, y[0] = %p y[3] = %p y[4] = %p",
     &x[0],&y[0],&y[3],&y[4]);

результат

    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ ./a
    x[0] = 0022FF40, y[0] = 0022FF3C y[3] = 0022FF3F y[4] = 0022FF40
    c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $

Comment: @avp, да, действительно, спасибо)